# Why isn't my java program working?? It doesn't allow me to input my string statement scale.

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Here is the code I wrote to convert Fahrenheit to Celcius and vise versa. The teacher said we had to use switch statements.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hope 
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of degrees: ");
        double degrees = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the scale: ");
        String scale = keyboard.nextLine();

        switch(scale)
        {
        case "F":
        case "f":
            double fahrenheit = (degrees - 32) * .5556;
            System.out.println(degrees + scale + " equals " + fahrenheit + " degrees celcius");
            break;
        case "C":
        case "c":
            double celcius = (degrees + 32) * 1.8;
            System.out.println(degrees + scale + " equals " + celcius + " degrees Fahrenheit");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("I don't know what you're talking about. Chaw. ");
            break;

        }
    }

}
```

The problem is when I run it the program allows me to input degrees, then displays the print statement, and then just jumps to the default case without allowing me to input scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consume the new line. `Scanner.nextDouble()` will only read the next *token* as a double, without the line terminator. Either add `keyboard.nextLine()` after reading the double:

```
double degrees = keyboard.nextDouble();
keyboard.nextLine();
```

Or use `Double.parseDouble(String)` on the input line:

```
String degreesString = keyboard.nextLine();
double degrees = Double.parseDouble(degreesString);
```

Answer (score 2):

The  after the double you entered will be consumed by  `keyboard.nextLine();`

So you have to enter on `keyboard.nextLine();` more.

```
double degrees = keyboard.nextDouble();
keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter the scale: ");
String scale = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Comment: how does it get consumed exactally. I don't get it.

Comment: @jiija: next double will only read the double value from the console. The you have the line feed s an Input and this will be read by the nextLine.

Comment: @jiija, when the user enters: "12.34<ENTER>" nextDouble() will only consume 12.34. The remaining "<ENTER>" will be left waiting until a nextLine() gets invoked.

Answer (score 0):

If the Scanner input utility is not compulsory, I would suggest using the BufferedReader.

```
package com.tempcalculator;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String degrees = getInput("Degrees?");
    String scale = getInput("Scale?");

    switch (scale.charAt(0)) {
        case 'F':
        case 'f':
            double fahrenheit = (Double.parseDouble(degrees) - 32) * .5556;
            System.out.println(degrees + scale + " equals " + fahrenheit + " degrees Celsius");
            break;
        case 'C':
        case 'c':
            double celsius = (Double.parseDouble(degrees) + 32) * 1.8;
            System.out.println(degrees + scale + " equals " + celsius + " degrees Fahrenheit");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Whoops! Error 404: Requested scale was not found. ");
            break;
    }
}


public static String getInput(String prompt) {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print(prompt);
    System.out.flush();

    try {
        return in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
    }

}
```

}